# Modify existing logrotate file using an ansible playbook

Tags: logging, ansible, logrotate

I'm looking to create an ansible playbook to rotate syslogs and daemon.logs in our environment. I'm not looking to use ansible-galaxy roles.

Ideally, i would need to just modify the existing `rsyslog` file in `/etc/logrotate.d` and add `/var/log/daemon.log` to the first curly block (see below).

I was referring to the following link, however im not able to fully grasp the concept as I am a new user of Ansible.

https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modifying-files/modifying-files/

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}

      }
```

Desired:

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/daemon.log
{
        rotate 14
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ansible `replace` module and `lineinfile` module you can complete this task.
No need to look for ansible galaxy roles. You can write simple playbook for this automation.